# Turn Nokogiri XML object to string without using .text

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I have an object which is a child of a `< td >` tag. The class is `ctext` and the relevant data is within the `< b >` tag.tag

I have selected the node using:

```
td.css(".ctext b")
```

and it seems to work. I get a result of something like:

```
< b >Flying< br >< br >At the beginning of each combat, choose first strike, vigilance, or lifelink. Creatures you control gain that ability until end of turn.< /b >
```

If I use:

```
td.css(".ctext b").text
```

to convert it to a string, I get:

```
FlyingAt the beginning of each combat, choose first strike, vigilance, or lifelink. Creatures you control gain that ability until end of turn.
```

What I need is to be able to convert the `td.css(".ctext b")`, which I think is a Nokogiri xml node to string without stripping the HTML tags. I need to keep the `< br >`s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `.inner_html` instead of `.text`.

Comment: Thanks!
I know this is sort of a separate question, but I'm running into an issue with the text of another element on the page. The page in question is: http://magiccards.info/gtc/en/1.html . When i try and parse the Italic part of the page i get a weird overlap: <br>-Predak, Gateless freemageinto an attack, without fear or hesitation, in that instant you may attain greatness."

Answer (score 7):

The [`to_s`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-to_s) method on [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) should return the full HTML or XML representation, including tags:

> **to_s()**
>   Turn this node in to a string. If the document is HTML, this method returns html. If the document is XML, this method returns XML.

So I would try this:

```
td.css(".ctext b").to_s
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an issue where line is overwriting itself.

The page content is: